# How can I hide the computer name in macbook

Tags: macos, pdf

how can I hide the "reviewer details" in a pdf file as referee for a scientific paper for macbook.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you asking how to edit the metadata in a PDF file, or is the text visible on the page?

Comment: The message I took today was like that.                                                                    "I would like to thank you for your comments on this paper
You reported many comments on the pdf version and unfortunately these bring with them your name and surname
I would like to ask you to send us the comments anonymized"

Comment: I recommend you ask the institution asking for a review about tips on how to do it. // You do not mention in your question what you did. Only that you reviewed a PDF. Did you add comments to the PDF? Which software did you use to do the review?